# Best schedule for multiple ETL jobs with dependencies

Tags: database, etl, job-scheduling

I am scheduling ETL jobs that takes data from mysql, transforms, then dumps it back into mysql. Most of the jobs take less than a minute, but some of the jobs take a few minutes to complete.
Some of the jobs have dependencies e.g. job A might re-create a table that is an input for job B, so job B is dependent on A. There are also relatively complex dependencies, e.g. job C depends on job A, while job D depends on job B, and finally job E depends on both C and D.

What is the best schedule for these jobs?
I want to avoid simultaneous reading/writing on the same tables. Not sure what else I should avoid...

Currently I have been spacing them apart by their execution duration multiplied by a safety margin. This was working OK, especially when I only had less than 10 jobs to schedule. Now it's starting to get more crowded with multiple jobs running simultaneously and there are rare times when one job doesn't finish before the next dependent job and it hangs the rest of the dependent jobs.
I have been thinking about spacing them apart so that dependent jobs aren't running one after another. Any established methods of doing this?

Comment: I have a similar use case. Did you manage to find a solution? I'm looking at Apache Airflow (https://airflow.apache.org/)